# Badge For Highest Badges Earned In a Day

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request

Why isin't there a badge for highest number of badges earned in a day?

Example: You earn a badge 'A' for earning 5 badges in the same day.

Is it because people may try to use unfair methods to earn it? Or is it because it hasen't been thought about?

Comment: I've earned a couple of dozen badges in an hour, and don't favor your suggestion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Badges are supposed to encourage people to

1. learn about site functions (mainly bronze badges)
2. provide some reward for doing useful actions e.g. reviews

Trying to get as many badges as possible as soon as possible really doesn't fit into either of those categories. You'd encourage gaining badges without thinking about what they are for or what you've done to get them i.e. robo behaviour and we have enough of a problem with that already.